# Connecting to Google Places API from a .Net MVC application

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, google-places-api

I am trying to connect to `Google Places API` from an `.net MVC 4` application that acts as a server for a Andorid based application as `Google Places API` can’t directly be contacted from the device.

Android device will send request to this `.Net` App and it will retrieve Places data from Google API and return it to Android device.

I am not very experienced with `.Net MVC` so I need to ask that is there any particular pattern or architecture I should use for this that could help me performance and productivity wise, or I can simply make web service calls from a controller and return it back?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample request made to the places API to search for a library within a specified range of a given latitude and logitude. This uses [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient) to send the request. Note that the response will be in json and there are a variety of ways to deserialize it and act on the data.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
        var latitude = -33.8670522;
        var longitude = 151.1957362;
        var key="your api key here";  

        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={0},{1}&radius=500&type=library&key={2}", latitude, longitude, key));

        //here is an example of using Newtonsoft.JSON to deserialize the response 
        //json string which assumes you have a class called PlacesApiQueryResponse
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlacesApiQueryResponse>(response);
}
```